# Laravel MIME Validator not working as expected

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

i'm creating an API in Laravel 5.5 and this API supports receiving some files for profile pictures and such.

I want to limit this through a *form request* to accept only **JPG** and **PNG** images and i'm setting up my Form Request as follows:

```
    'picture'    => 'nullable|image|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg|max:2000' // 2000KB or around 2MB per picture
```

Then, on my PHPUnit/Codeception tests i'm sending a fake image using Laravel's own `fake` static method as follows

```
'picture' => UploadedFile::fake()->image("hello.svg")
```

If i DD the image file that is being sent when i run the test it correctly lists it's **MIMEType** as `image/svg+xml`, however, somehow this passes validation and comes out the other end and that should not be the case as my rule *should* limit only PNG or JPG files.

Does anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your form has an attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

You can read about the enctype attribute here : [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Answer (score 0):

you wrote wrong syntax to validate picture type in picture validation.

you need just to create picture validation like this :

```
'picture' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png|max:2000'
```